# How do you compile multiple files in different folders in D?

Tags: d

```
project
---|source
------ |controllers
-------|models
-------|lib
----------|field.d
-------|app.d
```

I run dub but I get this error:

> Error: module field from file ... conflicts with another module field from
>   file source/lib/field.d

field.d looks like this:

```
   module field;

    class Field(T){

        this(T def_val,bool required,string help_text);

        bool validate();
        private bool _validate(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always put a module statement in any file that is going to be imported, and use a package name consistently as well to avoid conflicts.

So, instead of calling it simply `module field;`, call it `module myapplication.field;`, or even `module myapplication.lib.field;`, and of course, also import it by the same full name when you use it.

I'm not sure if dub will just work like that though (I don't use it personally), but the language lets you give a module any name, even if it doesn't match the filename, which helps in situations like this, avoiding name conflicts.

In general, if you give them all full, unique names, then compile them all at once: `dmd app.d lib/field.d [and any other files your project has]`, things will just work.

Comment: It is not allowed to for modules to be named arbitrarily as modules should have a one-to-one correspondence with the filesystem.
Check http://dlang.org/module.html.

His `field` module should be named `lib.field` in this case.

Comment: That's a common misconception. There's one module per file, but the name does *not* have to match, and it is actually impossible for them to match anyway! One file can have multiple names and/or multiple parent directories. The only important thing is that the compiler can find it, and if you list the files on the command line yourself, it always can. Typically, you do want it to be a close match since otherwise you'll confuse people who are trying to find a particular source file, but you also want it to be unique, so a project name helps, and there's times when the module to be continued

Comment: There's times when the module name deliberately doesn't match - you can use this to do compile time configuration. For example, in one of my work projects, there's multiple builds for different clients, with a number of changes that dmd's -version switch alone couldn't do. My solution was to `import myapp.config;` at the usage point, then have separate files: foo_config.d, bar_config.d, etc., each one of them being called `module myapp.config;`. Then, I choose which config file to pass to dmd when doing a client build and boom, instant customization, neatly separated into independent files.

Comment: I am literally quoting the language reference in this: `Modules have a one-to-one correspondence with source files. The module name is the file name with the path and extension stripped off.`
So I believe that this is something that the compiler allows, at least currently, but that may stop working at some point in time.

Regarding your use case, personally I would have imported the configuration as a file rather than a module, and inserted it in `myapp.config`.

Comment: That second sentence is wrong - that's only the *default* name, but the module declaration lets you change that. This part from later on in that same file is more accurate: `The ModuleDeclaration sets the name of the module and what package it belongs to. If absent, the module name is taken to be the same name (stripped of path and extension) of the source file name.` Further down as well shows an example that doesn't match, `If the file name of a module is an invalid module name (e.g. foo-bar.d), you may use a module declaration to set a valid module name:` So just a doc bug here.